# Flink Kubernetes operator | how to pass s3 key/secrets to flink-conf.yaml

Tags: kubernetes, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I'm using Flink's Kubernetes pod operator (in AWS EKS cluster) to deploy flink job and trying to set up AWS S3 location directory for checkpointing and savepoint. I have to pass s3 access/secret keys to `flink-conf.yaml` but I don't want to put plain credential strings in the config and commit to git.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  namespace: flink-stage
  name: flink-secrets
type: Opaque
  data:
    # base64 encoded!
    s3.access_key: <key>
    s3.secret_key: <secret>
```

How to refer the secrets in conf yaml, I've tried using secret ref but it doesn't work

```
apiVersion: flink.apache.org/v1beta1
kind: FlinkDeployment
metadata:
  name: nrt-sessionizer
spec:
  image: flink:1.17
  flinkVersion: v1_17
  flinkConfiguration:
    taskmanager.numberOfTaskSlots: "4"
    s3.access-key:
      valueFrom:
        secretKeyRef:
          key: s3.access_key
          name: flink-secrets
    s3.secret-key:
      valueFrom:
        secretKeyRef:
          key: s3.secret_key
          name: flink-secrets
```

---

```
error: error validating "infra/flink-k8/overlays/prod": error validating data:
 [ValidationError(FlinkDeployment.spec.flinkConfiguration.s3.access-key): invalid type for org.apache.flink.v1beta1.FlinkDeployment.spec.flinkConfiguration: got "map", expected "string",
 ValidationError(FlinkDeployment.spec.flinkConfiguration.s3.secret-key): invalid type for org.apache.flink.v1beta1.FlinkDeployment.spec.flinkConfiguration: got "map", expected "string"]; 
if you choose to ignore these errors, turn validation off with --validate=false
```

> Note: changing flink-conf.yaml contents using InitContainer doesn't
> work because ConfigMaps are read only.

Please suggest how to pass secrets to `flink-conf.yaml`.

Comment: configuring inside the application through code also doesn't work  
 https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-24595

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved this issue by setting the below config in Deployment yaml: K8 pods are running in EKS with an assumed role. Instead of passing key/secret we can tell Flink to use the below-mentioned class to assume the role provided in the ENV variable.

> NOTE: You can pass different authentication provider classes provided by [AWS Auth SDK](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/auth/package-summary.html) and avoid passing key/secret in the Yaml.

```
fs.s3a.aws.credentials.provider: "com.amazonaws.auth.WebIdentityTokenCredentialsProvider"
```

---

```
apiVersion: flink.apache.org/v1beta1
kind: FlinkDeployment
metadata:
  name: nrt-sessionizer
spec:
  image: flink:1.17
  flinkVersion: v1_17
  flinkConfiguration:
    taskmanager.numberOfTaskSlots: "4"
    fs.s3a.aws.credentials.provider: "com.amazonaws.auth.WebIdentityTokenCredentialsProvider"
```